# How to pass environment variables to Zeus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zeus

When I run zeus:

```
MY_VAR=MY_VALUE zeus start
```

Environment stays with that that variable, let's say I want to run Rails server with `MY_VAR=MAY_VALUE_2`

I have tried:

```
MY_VAR=MAY_VALUE_2 zeus s
```

But it does not work. I am using oh-my-zsh, in case that's important.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure you can - as far as i understand the forked child is always going to inherit the environment of the parent process, ie the zeus server.

Comment: You might be able to use zeus.json to set these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't know if you still need help with but if you want to be able to store environmental variables in a file you can use the `custom_plan.rb` that is generated with `zeus init`. Below is a copy of my file. I am using Omniauth and need my keys to be easily changeable. You can add server only variables by overloading the `server` method instead, just know that your initializers will be ran before the server command.

```
require 'zeus/rails'

class CustomPlan < Zeus::Rails

  def boot

    # Omniauth Keys

    # GOOGLE+
    ENV['GPLUS_KEY']       = 'xxx'
    ENV['GPLUS_SECRET']    = 'xxx'

    # FACEBOOK
    ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY']    = 'xxx'
    ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'] = 'xxx'

    super # Finish boot
  end
end

Zeus.plan = CustomPlan.new
```

Comment: One of the main points of using an environment variable instead of a settings file is that it's not easy to accidentally commit things like GPLUS_SECRET and FACEBOOK_SECRET. Using a file such as this brings this problem back. I wish there was a better option.

Comment: If I add env variables in custom_plan.rb then my zeus start command fails. Appending env variables at the start of zeus start command worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Passing it in zeus start

`SOME_ENV_VAR=test zeus start`